# Aligning one fixed and one scroll-able element next to each other

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter bootstrap, and have the following two major div elements side by side (both `span6`).  I was wondering if there is a way that I could get element 1 (seen below) to have a fixed vertical length, while element 2 can still be allowed to scroll vertically based on the data that it needs to display, but *within* the visual vertical length set by element 1.

As an addendum, I have been trying to use `background-color` as a attribute within one of the span6 div to get the background colored, but currently its not showing anything... is there any attribute that I need to add?

Thanks!

```
 ------------  ------------
|            ||            |
|   fixed    ||scroll-able |
|   element  ||  element   |
|            ||            |
|     1      ||     2      |
|            ||            |
 ------------  ------------
```

**Addendum**

Here my css:

```
.principal-element {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #006faa;
  background-color:#C0C0C0;
  height:900px;
  position:fixed;
  float:left;
  h1 {
    color: white;
  }
}

.secondary-element {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

And what shows up in the html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="span6">
    <div class="principal-element">
        <h1><%= link_to "Text and stuff", "#" %></h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class ="span6 offset6">
    <div class="secondary-element">
        <ol class="microposts">
            <li> Blah blah a lot of stuff
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be completely missing a step here, but isn't this roughly what you're looking to achieve in the first problem?

```
<html>

    <div class="element one">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element two">
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
    </div>

</html>

<style>

    div.element {
    width:200px;
    background-color:#C0C0C0;
    height:90px;
    color:#606060;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:10px;
    position:fixed;
    float:left;
    }

    div.two {
    overflow:scroll;
    margin-left:240px;
    }

</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QYtsr/2/

Comment: Thanks!  I checked out the jsfiddle and definitely looked like it was working.. however, when put into Bootstrap's `span6` tags in app, the color, as well as the fixed length did not appear.  I'll post more code into the body of my question.

Comment: Very strange, looking at the code you entered I'm unsure as to why it wouldn't work. span* should only affect widths, and should be contained by a parent with the class 'row' (unless you've switched from the stock bootstrap classes) as far as I know. That's the only thing I can see that's missing.

Sorry, I wish I could help more but I'm not too versed myself.

Comment: I think I have made some progress getting the `span` thing to not interfere.  Your post definitely put me on the right direction - thanks again!